# I need to make a call from my app, and at the end return to the app in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tel, telprompt

I need to make a call from my app, and at the end return to the app, as I can do it using only tel: since telprompt creates a pop up and I do not want it. there is a solution ???

Comment: I didn't find such a way

Comment: if you are talking about _cellular_ calls, you can't do it; but if it is a kind of VOIP, there any many frameworks are available which you can implement into your app.

Comment: are not VoIP calls are cellular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only options that I know of are `tel:` and `telprompt:`, the former calling a number without a prompt but not returning users back to their application, the latter prompting users to call the number and also returning them back to the application afterwards. As far as I'm aware, these are the only two APIs to make phone calls in iOS, so you have to choose which you prefer.